# php/pdo/mysql accessing selected row from a select * in html table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, session-variables

I'm building a website with a light back-office order management system. I am encountering a technical difficulty as I'm still in the php learning process. 
I have a php menu which launches different scripts and this one (waiting_orders.php) displays waiting orders in a html table. By clicking on the order primary key stored in a button, the user should be able to browse the order details with order_detail.php (join client table and so on). The two scripts execute fine but order_detail.php doesn't show expected result.

**waiting_orders.php**

```
    <?php   
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['detail']))
    { header('Location: order_detail.php'); }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
all html stuff
    <?php // all db connexion stuff
        $status = "waiting";
        $select = $connexion -> prepare("SELECT orderID,order_date,order_qty,order_amount
        FROM Orders WHERE status = '$status'"
        );
        $select->execute();
        $result = $select->fetchall();
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
        echo '<tr><th>Order no</th><th>Date</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Amount</th></tr>';

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $_SESSION['order_key'] = $row['orderID']; // orderID is the primary key

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<form method="post" action=""><td><button class="btn btn-danger bold" type="submit" name="detail" value="'.$_SESSION['order_key'].'">'.$row['cmdID'].'</button></td></form>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_date'],'</td>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_qty'],'</td>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_amount'],'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }                           
        echo '</table>';
?>
```

**order_detail.php**

```
    <?php 
session_start();
$select_key = $_SESSION['order_key'] ;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
all html stuff
<?php  // all db connexion stuff
$select = $connexion -> prepare(
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '$select_key'"  
);
```

As you may guess, order_detail.php always displays last row and not the current orderID selected by the user. I tried using an array but without success as I don't really see how to handle it. Thanks.

Comment: you're doing this in your loop => $_SESSION['order_key'] = $row['orderID'];  so the last orderID will be saved on the session.

Comment: To debug order_detail.php I would try    `echo "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '$select_key'" `   so that you can see the actual query that is being made to the database, then copy and paste this in phpMyAdmin if you have it, to see if it gives you the expected result or an error message.

Comment: correct Dr.Stitch this is why I tried to store orderID keys in an array, let's say $keys=array(); and $keys[]=$row['orderID']; and $_SESSION['order_key']=$keys; I've got all orderID keys but still don't know which one the user clicked on.

Comment: grateful I know order_detail.php receives the wrong orderID (the last one). I need waiting_orders.php to pass the good value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are storing the orderID into `$_SESSION['order_key']` and then using the `$_SESSION` variable to output the orderID in the form.

Try this.

**waiting_orders.php**

```
    <?php   
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
all html stuff
    <?php // all db connexion stuff
        $status = "waiting";
        $select = $connexion -> prepare("SELECT orderID,order_date,order_qty,order_amount
        FROM Orders WHERE status = '$status'"
        );
        $select->execute();
        $result = $select->fetchall();
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
        echo '<tr><th>Order no</th><th>Date</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Amount</th></tr>';

        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $_SESSION['order_key'] = $row['orderID']; // orderID is the primary key

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="order_detail.php'"><td><button class="btn btn-danger bold" type="submit" name="detail" value="'.$row['orderID'].'">'.$row['cmdID'].'</button></td></form>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_date'],'</td>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_qty'],'</td>';
            echo '<td>',$row['order_amount'],'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }                           
        echo '</table>';
?>
```

***order_detail.php***

```
    <?php 
session_start();
$select_key = $_POST['detail'];
/*
    You can also set the $_SESSION variable here if it is needed elsewhere
*/
// $_SESSION['order_key'] = $_POST['detail'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
all html stuff
<?php  // all db connexion stuff
$select = $connexion -> prepare(
"SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '$select_key'"  
);
```

Comment: Thanks but waiting_orders.php is passing the wrong $select_key and I'm not familiar with oracle as I use mysql/pdo.

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. I wrote wrapper classes for pdo_mysql & pdo_oci and must have copied from the wrong one. I have seen 1 thing though... I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time, your answer solved my problem. My users can now prepare orders :)